# How to differentiate $ y=\sin^2(2x)\cos(x) $?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, algebraic-curves

I was solving some A Level past papers and I came across this question. We have the equation of the line $ y=\sin^2(2x)\cos(x) $ for $ 0\leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2} $ and there is a maximum point M. We need to find the x coordinate of M. I know that at maximum points, the $dy/dx$ would be 0 which would help us find M. However, I am unable to differentiate this equation. I used the rule $dy/dx=u'v+v'u$ where u and v are functions of x, but am getting the wrong answer. I would really appreciate if someone would guide me through this question and give me the answer. I tried WolframAlpha but am a free member so I won't get step-by-step instructions, and the paper's mark scheme doesn't have a good explanation of steps. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to use the chain rule in addition to the product rule.

Comment: @Logophobic How to? I'm sorry, but I didn't understand.

Comment: Chain rule: If $f(x)=h(g(x))$ then $f'(x)=h'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$.

Comment: Btw I think you get get a free 2 week W|A pro trial if you sign up with email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = {\sin^2(2x)}\left(-\sin(x)\right) + {\cos(x)}\left(2\sin(2x)\cos(2x)\right)\cdot{2}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I understood the first part term, but didn't understand how you got $cos(x)(2sin(2x)cos(2x)).2$. This might be a very basic question, but differentiating and integrating trigonometric functions was always a bit hard for me. Thanks!

Comment: Hint #2: Use the product, power and chain rules of differentiation.  In particular, $\left(2\sin(2x)\cos(2x)\right)\cdot{2}$ is just the derivative of $\sin^2(2x)$.

Comment: Oh, I'm pretty sure that's where the problem lies. I'm comfortable with applying the product rule, but need to work on my differentiation and integration of trig functions. Thank you!

Comment: No problem!  Good luck with studying differential and integral calculus in general!  =)

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any tips or resources? I'm aware of Khanacademy and PatrickJMT. Any other YouTubers or websites you know?

Comment: I highly recommend Khan Academy.  Sorry I am not aware of any other websites specific for your learning goal.  What I could suggest is for you to browse other *basic* questions on differentiation of trigonometric functions in MSE.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$y=f(u(x))\times g(v(x))$$ and apply both product rule and chain rule $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{df(u(x))}{du(x)} \times\frac{du(x)}{dx}\times g(v(x))+f(u(x))\times\frac{dg(v(x))}{dv(x)}\times \frac{dv(x)}{dx}$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand that. Would it be possible to relate this to the question? I feel that would aid understanding. Thanks!